# How to calculate previous time and total time when inserting current time?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to store current project duration with project name in a table. which also consist of current duration, previous duration and total duration.

I am entering project name and current duration in the form and storing to the table, but how can I calculate the previous duration and total duration when I add more projects?

```
projects_id - int (auto increment)
project - varchar
current_time - int
previous_time - int
total_time - int
```

First I will initialize `previous_time` and `total_time` to 0

Then while inserting new rows I'll update project name and current time, the previous time and total time has to be automatically calculated.

Comment: Show your table description.

Comment: Can you post a sample data set with expected output?

Comment: @Ravinder i have updated the question with table description

Comment: @NishantShrivastava if i add project name and current time like sample and 8(hrs) it ll store like sample 8hrs. then next time if i add current time to same project the previous time has to be added to current time

Comment: `current_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` also switch `previous_time` to `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` and update total time based on the value of the two. In fact you don't even need total time since you can do that on the fly on the query.

Comment: can you please explain with a example query? @Prix

Comment: @user3239311 you will have to read more on MySQL there is a lot of functionality you're missing by not properly using the data type you have within MySQL.

Comment: @Prix thanks for you response. i am very new to mysql and php. can you guide me in this issue now?

Comment: Here is a good place to start, [MySQL Date and Time functions,](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) along with [Choosing the Right Type for a Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/choosing-types.html) and [Storage requeriments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

Comment: Sample structure/query that you can consider has been posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Table structure you can consider:

```
mysql> desc project;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                      |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------------------+
| project_id    | int(1)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment             |
| project       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL                |                            |
| current_t     | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|
| previous_time | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                            |
| total_time    | time        | YES  |     | NULL                |                            |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Sample data

```
mysql> select * from project;
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| project_id | project | current_t           | previous_time       | total_time |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|          1 | test    | 2014-03-06 12:36:34 | 2014-03-06 10:27:19 | 00:00:00   |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

SQL to do the update you are looking for:

```
REPLACE INTO project (project_id,previous_time,total_time) 
SELECT project_id,current_t,total_time + TIMEDIFF(NOW(),current_t) 
FROM project 
WHERE project_id = 1
```

Updated table:

```
mysql> select * from project;
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| project_id | project | current_t           | previous_time       | total_time |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|          1 | NULL    | 2014-03-06 12:41:22 | 2014-03-06 12:36:34 | 00:04:48   |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You can check if you want automatic updating of current_t or not. If you don't want it drop the 'on update  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' property from the current_t field ... and add bits in the replace query accordingly.

Comment: @Prix thanks for the detailed explanation.. i set the database tables but i don't know the php insert syntax

Comment: @user3239311 wrong person, that is Nishant's explanation.

Comment: Oops sry @NishantShrivastava thank u so much. can you tell the sample php code also?

Comment: @Prix Anyway thank you again. still am not able to work with it.

Comment: The SQL is there.. search any standard PHP code sample to execute a query on your DB and with that code execute the SQL query mentioned.